# почему не выводит нужные символы?

Tags: python, файлы, символы

я только учусь, и у меня есть практическое задание:

У нас есть текстовый файл с данными о ящиках в таком формате: "type_of_fruit (тип
фрукта) количество фруктов название склада(A, B или C)". Данные разделены пробелом.
Мы должны найти ответы на следующие вопросы, написав код с функциями для каждой
задачи:
Какие виды фруктов у нас есть? Составьте список.

содержимое файла выглядит таким образом:

```
бананы 2 A
ананасы 45 C
кокосы 102 B
бананы 78 A
апельсины 135 B
бананы 7 C
бананы 212 A
апельсины 65 C
кокосы 12 A
ананасы 17 C
бананы 117 C
кокосы 65 A
бананы 55 B
апельсины 34 C
бананы 32 B
кокосы 2 C
ананасы 77 C
бананы 89 C
кокосы 45 A
апельсины 89 B
кокосы 101 B
бананы 132 C
ананасы 34 B
бананы 56 B
апельсины 84 A
кокосы 28 A
апельсины 28 A
бананы 54 B
ананасы 43 A
апельсины 53 C
```

мой код выглядит так:

```py
def func(x):
    x = open(x, 'r')
    s = []
    for i in x:
        a = i.split()
        if a[0] not in s:
            s.append(a[0])
        else:
            pass
    return s
f = func('Файлы_задание.txt')
print(f)
```

выводит вот такой набор символов:

```py
['п»їР±Р°РЅР°РЅС‹', 'Р°РЅР°РЅР°СЃС‹', 'РєРѕРєРѕСЃС‹', 'Р±Р°РЅР°РЅС‹', 'Р°РїРµР»СЊСЃРёРЅС‹']
```

почему?

Comment: Файл в какой кодировке? Надо указать эту кодировку при чтении файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
x = open(x, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: получилось! только теперь почему-то первая строчка "бананы 2 A" читается как "\ufeffбананы", не знаете почему так?

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь. \ufef в начале строки это маркер последовательности байтов(BOM - Byte Order Mark) - необязательный символ обозначения Юникода, который иногда присутствует в файлах. Попробуйте вместо utf-8 использовать utf-8-sig . Эта вариация включает в себя BOM.